# How to Pass Textbox values from one page to bind another page in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages.  In posts.aspx I have one image upload, a textarea, and a submit button. When I click on the submit button it will save the image and textarea content to the database When I am logged in. These images, content are to bind the gridview in another page (i.e lists.aspx). I can't get the posts.aspx's content value.

**Posts.aspx**

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuPostImageUrl" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 80px" />
    <br>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPostTitle"  runat="server"
        Style="font-family: comfortaa, sans-serif; margin-left: 25px; color: red; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;"
        Text="Please Enter Your Post Title : ">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostTitle" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="margin-left: 13px">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <br>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPostDetails" runat="server"
        Style="font-family: comfortaa, sans-serif; margin-left: 25px; color: red; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;" 
        Text="Please Enter Your Comments : ">
    </asp:Label>
    <textarea id="txtPostDetails" runat="server" 
        class="comments" 
        cols="20" 
        rows="5" 
        style="width: 592px;"
        onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
        onblur="this.placeholder = 'Give Us Your Valid Comment'"
        placeholder="Give Us Your Valid Comment">
    </textarea>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEnteredPostComment" runat="server"
        Style="-webkit-border-radius: 10px; -ms-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
        border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 850px; margin-top: 15px;border: 0px solid; padding: 10px;" 
        Text="Enter Your Post" 
        ValidationGroup="UsersPostComment"
        OnClick="btnEnteredPostComment_Click" />
</div>
```

**Posts.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnEnteredPostComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=113.193.127.110;Initial Catalog=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;User ID=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;Password=[IW_Dev_MindVsHeart123$]");
    connection.Open();
    string link = "";
    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        if (fuPostImageUrl.HasFile)
        {
            string fname = fuPostImageUrl.FileName;
            string fpath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
            int flen = fuPostImageUrl.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            string fext = Path.GetExtension(fname);
            fext = fext.ToLower();
            link = "~/Images/" + fname;
            if (flen < 1048576)
            {
                if (fext == ".jpg" || fext == ".png" || fext == ".gif" || fext == ".bmp")
                {
                    fuPostImageUrl.SaveAs(fpath + fname);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Only image files are allowed');</script>");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Max file size allowed is 1 MB');</script>");
            }

        }
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SavePost", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postimageurl", link);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", txtPostTitle.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", txtPostDetails.InnerText);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdby", Session["UserId"]);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Your Comment Posted Successfully . Do You Want Post another one ? . ');", true);
        txtPostTitle.Text = "";
        txtPostDetails.InnerText = "";
    }
    else
    {
        txtPostTitle.Text = "";
        txtPostDetails.InnerText = "";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Your Session Expired or Login to Comment . ');", true);
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

**lists.aspx**

```
<div class="rounded_corners" style="width: 300px">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvrecords" runat="server" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        DataKeyNames="PostId"
        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" 
        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
        RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" 
        RowStyle-ForeColor="#3A3A3A" 
        Width="300" 
        OnRowCommand="gvrecords_RowCommand"
        OnRowDataBound="gvrecords_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PostImageUrl" HeaderText="Post Image" 
                    ControlStyle-Height="100" 
                    ControlStyle-Width="100" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Post Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Content" HeaderText="Post Comment" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Comment">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" 
                            CommandName="Delete_Comment" 
                            CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("PostId") %>'>
                            Delete Comment
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**lists.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        BindUserDetails();
    }
}

protected void BindUserDetails()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=113.193.127.110;Initial Catalog=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;User ID=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;Password=[IW_Dev_MindVsHeart123$]");
    connection.Open();
    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("BindExistsUserPosts", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Session["UserId"]);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Session["PostId"]);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        gvrecords.DataSource = ds;
        gvrecords.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please Login to Comment . ');", true);
    }
    connection.Close();
}

protected void gvrecords_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Delete_Comment")
    {

        int posid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=113.193.127.110;Initial Catalog=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;User ID=IW_Dev_MindVsHeart;Password=[IW_Dev_MindVsHeart123$]");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DeleteExistsUserPost", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postid", posid);
        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        if (result == 1 && Session["UserId"] != null)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + Title + " Post deleted Successfully')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "alert('Please Login to Delete Comment . ');", true);
        }
        BindUserDetails();
    }

}

protected void gvrecords_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string title = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Title"));
        LinkButton lnkbtnresult = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkdelete");
        lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + title + "')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your file saving successfully in file path?

Comment: yes . I am saving the file in the proper file path ..

Comment: let me get it clear..when u post something from page Posts.aspx.cs it saves all data to DB right? and when you relogin to site u have GirdView which must show the Posted content of that specific user? if i am wrong plz clarify..and what error do u get? plz post your StoredProcedure too..

Comment: When I loggedin and post something in posts.aspx and go for another page called lists.aspx .In this page I want to access posts.aspx posting content in gridview style .

Comment: If file is saved correctly, the problem is uploaded file not saved to database, right? Or the saved record not shown in grid view?

Comment: it saved in the database . I checked it . I want to how do  i connect these two pages and access the values from one page to another .

Comment: How do you want to connect? What you have to do exactly?

Comment: You want to show the Posted content to a gridview which is on list.aspx  when "Post" button is clicked right?

Comment: yes sir you are right .

Comment: then whats the problem? what error you get plz check my edited answer..you are not able to post the ERROR YET that u got..plz do write the error that u get...so we can help you & StoredProcdure too :( and plz check the edited Answer carefully..! This will work! i have tested it..!

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following:

**lists.aspx.cs**

**Change From:**

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    BindUserDetails();
}
```

**To:**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindUserDetails();
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: then what was the error on page u r getting? plz specify indetail and also post your StoreProcedure too..!I have tried this code and must work fine! Also try by debugging to knw whether you get rows in DataSet? probably your are not able to explain it clearly...:(